# The radio and checkbox buttons are not getting rendered in a Spotify app.

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to use HTML radio buttons in my **Spotify app**.
When the **Inspector** tool is used, the code for radio button is present there, but the radio button is not getting rendered in the browser inside the Spotify client. I am also getting the same result for the checkbox.

The same code is used with normal browsers like IE, Mozilla, or Chrome and the radio button gets rendered without any trouble.

Can anybody tell me why the radio button is not getting rendered in the sandboxed browser inside the Spotify client?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post says it's a bug:
[Spotify - Using Checkbox UI elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297452/spotify-using-checkbox-ui-elements)

(didn't check on spotify api doc tought...)

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the radio button in the inspector, you can see that the input tag is getting the **-webkit-appearance:none** attribute set in the *sp://import/css/shared.css* and *sp://import/css/reset.css* files.

```
button, input, textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

The *sp://import/css/adam.css* and *sp://import/css/eve.css* files import the *sp://import/css/shared.css* file, which is how you are probably getting that attribute. The behavior only exists for the radio and checkbox types because the other input types are overridden elsewhere.

Tip: *If you view the css attributes in the inspector, you can actually check them to remove or re-add the style.*

**Solution**:

```
<input type="radio" style="-webkit-appearance:radio" />

<input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-appearance:checkbox" />
```

**Be warned:** *It may have been the intention of the developers to not show radio/checkbox buttons, so your app may have approval issues because of the UI guidelines.*

Regards, 
Kevin