# Spotify - Using Checkbox UI elements

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

When I'm trying to use checkboxes within my spotify application the element keeps blank.

E.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="incr" value="salami"> Salami
```

Just salami is displayed.

How should I build such elements within a spotify application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently a bug in the CSS which causes the checkbox to not render properly. You can override it and force it to render with webkit-appearance in CSS:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="incr" value="salami" style="-webkit-appearance: checkbox !important;" />
```